# EventHub connection using Python libraries azure-eventhub 5.0.0

Tags: python-3.x, azure-eventhub

All,

I inadvertently uninstalled EventHub [V1.3.3](https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub/1.3.3/) and installed the latest [V5.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub/#description). I had to change the code that I had but I never got it to work. **Below is the code:**

```py
    from azure.eventhub import EventHubProducerClient, EventData
    
    connection_str = 'Endpoint=sb://eventhubns20.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=eventhub20_pol;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxxxxx=;EntityPath=eventhub20' eventhub_name = 'eventhub20'
    
    client = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(connection_str, eventhub_name=eventhub_name)
    
    event_data_batch = client.create_batch()
```

Below is the error:

```sh
Traceback:
  File "C:\Users\grajee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\uamqp\authentication\cbs_auth.py", line 69, in create_authenticator
    self._cbs_auth = c_uamqp.CBSTokenAuth(
  File ".\src/cbs.pyx", line 73, in uamqp.c_uamqp.CBSTokenAuth.__cinit__
ValueError: Unable to open CBS link.
```

The error is on this line - `event_data_batch = client.create_batch()`.

Has anyone experienced this error. If it is too much of work I might have to rollback to V1.3.3. The Python version is V3.8.1 on Windows.

Comment: Please remove keys from your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is incorrect. The one you are using is `EventHub instance connection string`, but you should use `Eventhub Namespace connection string`.

The correct `Eventhub Namespace connection string` looks like this: `Endpoint=sb://xxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=policyName;SharedAccessKey=xxxx`.

Please follow the step below to get the **Event hub NameSpace connection string**(**not the event hub instance connection string**).

Nav to azure portal -> your Azure EventHub NameSpace -> Shared access policies -> click the policy you want to use -> then copy the connection string from `Connection string–primary key`.

The screenshot as blow:

[image]

Comment: PS C:\Users\grajee> & C:/Users/grajee/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe c:/DataEngineering/Python/Scripts/eventhub20send.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\grajee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\uamqp\authentication\cbs_auth.py", line 69, in create_authenticator
    self._cbs_auth = c_uamqp.CBSTokenAuth(
  File ".\src/cbs.pyx", line 73, in uamqp.c_uamqp.CBSTokenAuth.__cinit__
ValueError: Unable to open CBS link.

Comment: @GopinathRajee, please remove your first comment since it contains the key.

Comment: @GopinathRajee, this is not a bug since it works well at my side(python 3.8.1, eventhub 5.0.0). Can you try restart your machine, or create a virtual environment to check if the error still occurs?

Comment: I changed the key a bit before posting. Anyway I deleted the comment.

Comment: I restarted and tried. I also uninstalled, restarted and reinstalled and tried but it does not work

Comment: @GopinathRajee, can you create a virtual environment then install the package within the virtual environment? It's totally ok at my side.

Comment: @GopinathRajee, and also, could you reinstall [uamqp 1.2.5](https://pypi.org/project/uamqp/)?

Answer (score 0):

Your hostname doesn't resolve. Please make sure you are using an active Event hubs namespace.

```
>ping eventhubns20.servicebus.windows.net
Ping request could not find host eventhubns20.servicebus.windows.net. Please check the name and try again.
```

Comment: Here is the actual code with namespace and eventhub without the SAS Key

from azure.eventhub import EventHubProducerClient, EventData

connection_str = 'Endpoint=sb://eventhubns2020.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx='
eventhub_name = 'eventhub2020'

client = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(connection_str, eventhub_name=eventhub_name)

event_data_batch = client.create_batch()

Comment: There is no such Event Hubs namespace as "eventhubns2020", at least I could say that. Can you check your dashboard and create a brand new namespace and try with that? Your code is totally OK, it should run fine if there is an actual namespace and a hub under it.